# Run an executable in python Azure Function App

Tags: python, azure-functions, subprocess

I am running a python script through an http triggered azure function app. In the code I use a subprocess to run an executable with some input. This works fine locally as it runs on Windows. It is however unable to run the executable when I run it in the azure virtual machine - most likely due to it being a linux OS.

```
command = [Path_to_exe, Path_to_input]
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
proc.communicate()
```

The executable generates some files based on the input it is given, however it never generates any of the files on the virtual machine and doesn't give an error message. I was wondering if anyone knew how to call an executable with input in a function app.

Answer (score -1):

Create a time trigger (TimeTrigger function app) and run .exe file.

**Sample JSON file:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

If the above procedure not worked, then try the below mention

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash%2Cbrowser